# Why XmlDocument Validate doesn't throw any exception on xml with different namespace?

Tags: .net, xml, xsd

I validate some external XML documents against my XSD schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"       
           version="2011-03-01">
    <xs:element name="Document" type="DocumentType" />
    <xs:complexType name="DocumentType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Author" type="string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Receiver" type="string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

My schema doesn't use namespaces. **It works well but I have problem with certain XML. 
It is excel file saved as XLM**. It is completely invalid but my validator does not complain.
It is not valid according to my schema but my method does not throw any exception! It looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<office:document-content
    xmlns:office="foo">
    <office:bar></office:bar>
</office:document-content>
```

here's my code:

```
public void Validate(Stream streamWithXML)
{
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();

settings.Schemas.Add(settings.Schemas.Add("", xsdPath));
settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;

XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(streamWithXML, settings);
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load(reader);
ValidationEventHandler eventHandler = new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationEventHandler);
document.Validate(eventHandler);
reader.Close();
}

static void ValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
{}
```

Do you have any clue? I suppose it's because that specific document has some inline namespaces declarations. However online validator at http://tools.decisionsoft.com/schemaValidate/ throws exception:

> Cannot find the declaration of element
>   'office:document-content'.

which is correct. Is there any way to make .NET validator to throw exception in that case?

Comment: Hi JIp .. i know it's been a while but can you update your final solution I am having a same problem and can't find a way to fix it.?

Answer (score 2):

It does not throw an exception because it's not designed to.

The documentation shows that the intended usage is to create validation eventhandler and pass that into the Validate method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162371.aspx

This event handler contains warnings and errors if the document fails to validate, and you are expected to check this and handle validation error accordingly in the event handler you defined.

The ValidationEventArgs in your event handler contains the exception, severity, and messages:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.validationeventargs.aspx

The code example in the first link shows the poper usage.

Comment: I updated my code. It's like this one in msdn. I did wrote that it works correct and throws all schema exceptions except one specific file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [ValidationFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.validationflags.aspx) in the settings object to include `ReportValidationWarnings`.